# How to upvote 10 times or give reputation points away for really good answers?

Tags: discussion, reputation

I don't really care about reputation points. Perhaps some who answered my questions do care about it. How do I upvote their answers 10 times or at least give my reputation points away for their patience and/or very good answers?

Comment: You do know that particular levels of reputation points open up certain possibilities in the site right? Its good to not care about imaginary points from an ego perspective, but being able to correct blatant mistakes without it having to be reviewed is something that plenty of people cherish. And for that you minimally need 2k points.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's what [Bounties](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) are for!

From the help docs

> A bounty is a special reputation award given to answers. It is funded
>   by the personal reputation of the user who offers it, and is
>   non-refundable. If you see a question that has not gotten a
>   satisfactory answer, a bounty may help attract more attention and more
>   answers. Slice off anywhere from +50 to +500 of your own hard-earned
>   reputation, and attach it to any question as a bounty. You do not need
>   to be the asker of the question to offer a bounty on it.

Comment: Can a bounty be given after the answer is provided?

Comment: Yes.  Check out the linked page, it explains it pretty well.